# JavaScript validation does not stop submission to php script

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation

I want to validate my code with javaScript and determine if it is okay to submit to php. 
If it is correct I want the form to not submit to the php file that I have in 'action'. 
If it is inncorrect I do not want the form to submit to the php file, and I want to display an error message.

Right now the form uses "onsubmit="return Validate()""  to call the validation function which displays a message and returns false to stop the form action. The problem is that the form action does not get stopped, and still runs.  For some reason when I click the submit button twice the php message gets displayed then the java script message gets displayed.

My html form:

```
            <form action="<?= base_Url(); ?>index.php/Login/loginuser" onsubmit="return Validate();" method="post" name="Login" accept-charset= "utf-8"  >

            Username: <input type="text" name="Username"  maxlength="21" />
                <br><br>
            Password:   <input type="text" name ="password" maxlength="20" />
                <br><br>

                <input type = "submit" value = "Login" class = "loginbutton" />
            </form>
```

My java script function.

```
function Validate() {           


        document.getElementById("errorMSG").innerHTML = "Validate ran...";
        return false;

    }
```

From what I read online when onsubmit="return Validate()" gets returned false the form is supposed to not run. Thought this was right but cant figure out why its not working.

EDIT: I am useing codeigniter to display the url, and for other purposes on the project.

EDIT2: This is still not working... When the onsubmit is changed too, onsubmit="false" the php will not be called. Which is expected. When changed to onsubmit="true", the php will be called. Which is expected.

When onsubmit="return Validate();" and the Validation() function on says "return false;". It will for as expected. Same with return true. But when code gets placed in the function the boolean does not appear to be returned. The code below will not stop the php file from running when the login name is empty.

```
    function Validate() {           



        if (document.getElementsByName("Username")=="" )
        {
            document.getElementById("errorMSG").innerHTML = "Validate ran...";
            return false;               
        }
        else
        {
            return true;

        }
    }
```

I am testing with chrome and firefox. There are no error messages displayed in the console on google chrome. I am not familiar with the debug tool for fire fox but i see no error messages displayed either.

I am now going to change the jquery script line to an updated version, maybe it will help.. 
I am using code igniter with controllers, views, libraries...
Everything was working fine until i started with the javascript validation.

Comment: Use a proper event handler, and the [problem goes away](https://jsfiddle.net/bkqoLoea/)

Comment: That implementation did not work for me. Added the code and added id to form. Same result. php file was ran.

Comment: What do you mean by "If it is correct I want the form to not submit to the php file that I have in 'action'." ? How are we going to know if it is correct?

Comment: If nothing is working, you're doing something wrong. Did you open the console and check for errors.

Comment: Look, `return false` from your `submit` handler (however you attach it) and it will stop it from submitting. If you're not seeing that happen, look elsewhere (like `console.log`).

Comment: I will try your solution on different browsers. No console message using Chrome with my default user set up.

Answer (score 2):

You should use return false only when mandatory fields are empty

```
function Validate() {
  // check whether mandatory fileds have some value or not 
  // document.getElementsByName("Username") always returns an array and will be robust way to access value by  index 0 iin array like - document.getElementsByName("Username")[0]
  if(document.getElementsByName("Username")[0].value == ""  || document.getElementsByName("password")[0].value)
  {
    document.getElementById("errorMSG").innerHTML = "All fields required";
    return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Comment: This is the only reasonable answer.

Comment: The function does not return the boolean when logic is used in function, check EDIT2 on question.

Comment: You have an error in your code, it should be: `document.getElementsByName("Username").value == ''` and the one for `password` too.

Comment: I changed my answer please let me know whether it works or not?

Comment: Yes, there must be value in order to check with empty thanks @JaredFarrish

Answer (score 0):

1.It should be just "Validate()" for onsubmit, not "return Validate().

2. And use onclick instead of onsubmit

Try this

```
<input type = "submit" value = "Login" class = "loginbutton" onclick = "Validate()"/>
```

Comment: I will hit you back after a quick try

Comment: Add onclick attribute in the submit button instead of onsubmit in the form

Comment: Do not use `onclick`. Use `onsubmit` or attach an event listener to the `submit` event on the `FORM`. `return false` from the handler to prevent it from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one 100% work

```
onsubmit="myFunction();return false;"
```

Comment: Just add this to your form

Comment: This also did not work. The php file still got executed.

Comment: This stopped the submission and displayed the alert box with that message. When The alert line is commeted out leaving return false, the form does not submit. Then when false is changed to true, the form still does not submit.

Comment: This will always cancel the submit event on the form.

Comment: Because there is always a line next to the function call returning false